# Cannot run remote function inside Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, elixir

im trying to setup some unit tests with Elixir but running into this error below. What am I doing wrong?

```
cannot invoke remote function PropertyManager.Database.get/0 inside match
```

Here is my code:

property_manager_test.exs

```
defmodule PropertyManagerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "the truth" do
    assert 1 + 1 == 2
  end

  test "get value from db" do
    assert PropertyManager.Database.get() = "test this"
  end

end
```

database.ex

```
defmodule PropertyManager.Database do

  def get do
    "test this"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with `==` instead of `=`

What you're doing in your code is a pattern match, which means it will try to match the right side to the pattern on the left side. A pattern can't contain function calls, which is probably the cause of your error.

Comment: It's a frequent mistake, no need to be hard on yourself :-)